# Spring Boot - handle exception wrapped with BindException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am looking for a way to handle custom exception thrown during binding of request parameter to DTO field.

I have a cantroller in Spring Boot application as follows

```
@GetMapping("/some/url")
public OutputDTO filterEntities(InputDTO inputDTO) {
    return service.getOutput(inputDTO);
}
```

input DTO has few fields, one of which is of enum type

```
public class InputDTO {

    private EnumClass enumField;
    private String otherField;

    /**
     * more fields
     */
}
```

user will hit the URL in ths way

```
localhost:8081/some/url?enumField=wrongValue&otherField=anyValue
```

Now if user sends wrong value for enumField, I would like to throw my CustomException with particular message. Process of enum instance creation and throwing of exception is implemented in binder

```
@InitBinder
public void initEnumClassBinder(final WebDataBinder webdataBinder) {
    webdataBinder.registerCustomEditor(
            EnumClass.class,
            new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                @Override
                public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                    try {
                        setValue(EnumClass.valueOf(text.toUpperCase()));
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        throw new CustomException("Exception while deserializing EnumClass from " + text, exception);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Problem is that when exception is thrown it is impossible to handle it with

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public String handleException(CustomException exception) {
    // log exception
    return exception.getMessage();
}
```

Spring wraps initial exception with BindException. That instance contains my initial error message, but concatenated with other text which is redundant for me. I don't think that parsing and substringing that message is good...

Am I missing something? What is the proper way to get message from initial 
CustomException here?

Comment: I checked that the first thing. getClause() method of BindException instance returns null.

Comment: did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691790/spring-validation-how-to-have-propertyeditor-generate-specific-error-message?

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to handle exceptions thrown before entering your controller method by using `@ExceptionHandler` annotated methods. Spring handles these exceptions before entering the controller, by registering `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` handler.
This is the case of BindingException, thrown when Spring cannot bind request parameters to match your InputDTO object.
What you can do is to register your own handler (create a `Component` implementing `HandlerExceptionResolver` and `Ordered` interfaces), give it the highest priority in handling errors and play with exceptions as needed.
You have also to pay attention to `BindException` as it wrappes your custom exception, `CustomException.class`

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
import org.springframework.core.Ordered; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 
import org.springframework.validation.BindException; 
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


import yourpackage.CustomException;

@Component() 
public class BindingExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver, Ordered {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BindingExceptionResolver.class);

    public BindingExceptionResolver() {
    }

    private ModelAndView handleException(ObjectError objectError, HttpServletResponse response){
        if (objectError == null) return null;
        try {
            if(objectError.contains(CustomException.class)) {
                CustomException ex = objectError.unwrap(CustomException.class);
                logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return handleCustomException(ex, response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected ModelAndView handleCustomException(CustomException ex, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());
        return new ModelAndView();
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        try {
            if (ex instanceof org.springframework.validation.BindException) {
                BindException be = (BindException) ex;
                logger.debug("Binding exception in {} :: ({}) :: ({})=({})", be.getObjectName(), be.getBindingResult().getTarget().getClass(), be.getFieldError().getField(), be.getFieldError().getRejectedValue());
                return be.getAllErrors().stream()
                    .filter(o->o.contains(Exception.class))
                    .map(o ->handleException(o, response))
                    .filter(mv ->mv !=null)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception handlerException) {
            logger.error("Could not handle exception", handlerException); 
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @bogdotro. Your explanation is very helpful.