# How to handle MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I would like to handle exception thrown by validator.

I've made exception handler with ControllerAdvice annotation. It handles other exceptions but not MethodArgumentNotValidException.

Exception handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value
        = {ResourceNotFoundException.class, EntityNotFoundException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(
        RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {

    APIException apiException = new APIException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            ex.getMessage(), request);

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiException,
            new HttpHeaders(), apiException.getStatus(), request);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid
            (MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                 HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)     {
        APIException apiException = new APIException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            ex.getMessage(), request);

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiException,
            new HttpHeaders(), apiException.getStatus(), request);
    }
}
```

Validated class (without getters/setters etc.)

```
public class ClassQuery {
    @Min(1)
    private Integer minYear;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer year;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer maxYear;
    private String name;
    private String profile;
}
```

Rest api controller

```
@GetMapping
public Page<Class> getClasses(@Valid ClassQuery classQuery, Pageable pageable) {
    return classService.getClasses(classQuery, pageable);
}
```

Api Exception (without getters/setters etc.)

```
public class APIException {
    private Date timestamp;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private String path;

    public APIExceptionMessage(HttpStatus status, String message, WebRequest request) {
            this();
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
            this.path = getRequestURI(request);
    }
}
```

Currently I'm getting an empty response with BAD_REQUEST http status from validator while other exceptions are handled correctly. I've also tried no extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and handle it with @ExceptionHandler but it was ignoring my response body, in response it gave default error message. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: what does the `APIException` constructor look like that you have not posted?

Comment: I've edited the question, it's there. But as I wrote there is no problem with other exceptions, e.g ResourceNotFoundException

Comment: do you have getters and setters for the fields in ClassQuery? and how are you making the request?

Comment: Yes, just didn't post them

Comment: when you make the request you're passing all the values defined in ClassQuery in the query string?

Comment: Yes, e.g api/classes?year=2&name=abc, the class object gets those values

Comment: Yes,  I've also tried no extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and handle it with @ExceptionHandler like with ResourceNotFound but it was ignoring my response body, in response it gave default error message.

Comment: And use @RestControllerAdvice instead of @ControllerAdvice?

Comment: The same result

Comment: found something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786173/spring-boot-handle-exception-wrapped-with-bindexception

Comment: can you please post your stack trace where we can clearly see that this exception is being thrown in the first turn?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit too late.

I had the same problem where `MethodArgumentNotValidException` was not being handled by the class annotated as `ControllerAdvice`. In my case, I wanted to serialize and send a custom ErrorDTO Object as JSON to the HTTP Client.

**Solution:**
`MethodArgumentNotValidException` should be **imported from** `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Comment: i love you! After so many tries and error, i found this. thanks